# Flowplayer 5.1.1 (HTML5) - desire controls ALWAYS "on"?

Tags: html, html5-video, flowplayer

I've almost completed th flowplayer setup and most is working.

However...

I'd like to be able to create an instance of the new Flowplayer 5.1.1 (html5) where the controls are ALWAYS "on", i.e. "visible". Even after I move the mouse outside the video.

In the Flowplayer docs it says to add the class "fixed-controls" or "no-hover", but it does not seem to work. "fixed-controls" makes the controls disappear completely, while "no-hover" does not make any difference to the video.

This is what I am trying but...

these do NOT seem to work.

```
 <div class="flowplayer fixed-controls minimalist"><video src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/white/470x250.mp4"></video></div>
```

And...

```
<div class="flowplayer no-hover minimalist"><video src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/white/470x250.mp4"></video></div>
```

Any ideas how to make the controls always visible?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the begining I have the following. Like in the demo version.
< link rel="stylesheet" href="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.1.1/minimalist.css"/ >

Then I have the following.
< div class="flowplayer fixed-controls" >

That works fine for me.
The controls are always visible.

Regards
Ola Hedlin